# How can I automate tasks on a website without having access to the back-end?

Tags: html, automation

I'm in need of a software that automates simple repetitive (*logic*) tasks on a website.

*Note: I've looked into some of the website automation libraries out there like [Geb](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/) and [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io/) but these libraries seem to be focused on automating testing for developers. Meaning they have some of the functionality that I need but they also require access to the files of the website (i.e. running a Geb script in the back-end). Unfortunately, all I have to work with is the front-facing user application site of the site.*

An example of what I need the software to do:

1. Click the first link in a specific column of a table on the page.
2. On the new page that has been opened (a pre-filled HTML form) follow a set of logic:

   - If certain fields are non-empty, clear other fields
   - Otherwise, click some buttons
   - Etc.

*Note: These actions will sometimes result in popup windows appearing as a result of the actions been performed which then actions will need to be taken on these new popups.*

**Does such a software exist that suits my specific requirements?**

Comment: Would solutions like `selenium` or `phantomjs` be solutions you'd look at?  They'd take a fair bit of programming time on your end of course.  Would that be ok as part of the solution?

Comment: @EricRenouf I've briefly looked into `selenium` but I was under the impression that it is the backbone behind the libraries I've already mentioned (and thus needed access to the actual files). I haven't heard about `phantomjs` yet but I'm looking into it right now. The most important part of my question is that I do not have access to anything but the visible side of the web app. Meaning, I can't add any files/scripts into the application itself (therefore the software I'm looking for must be able to be run externally of the website it's modifying).

Comment: I don't know those libraries, so I'm not sure what it means to need the files.  Selenium automates a browser so makes Web requests then let's you interact with the page it gets back

Answer (score 2):

There are a whole bunch of different tools you could use depending on need. Here are a couple:

- [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) (mentioned by Eric)

  Would require a client to be running.
- [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (also mentioned by Eric)

  Can be run under Node.JS as a server but is command line/programming so no GUI. Certainly handles multiple windows.
- [iMacros](http://imacros.net)

  This has been knocking around for years, it has paid and free versions and works in the browser. Pretty easy to use. I'm fairly sure - but not 100% - that it will handle multiple windows.

Depending on what platform you are running on, you could probably use an OS automation tool such as [AutoIT](https://www.autoitscript.com) for Windows.

Comment: I would say Selenium. i would also note while AutoIt is an excellent app, it could only automate a browsers menus (I suppose it could clcik at x-y coords, but it can't select browser controls by name as it can for Windows)